# Proving that $V = U \oplus W$ where $W$ and $U$ are sets of eigenvectors of $S: V \to V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space, $S : V \to V$ be a linear map such that $S^2 = I$. Show that $V = U \oplus W$ where $U = \{u \in V : Su = u\}$ and $W = \{ w \in V : Sw = -w\}$.

For some context, in a previous part of the question, I proved that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $S$ then $\lambda = \pm1$.

To prove something is a direct sum of 2 sets of vectors, I have to prove that $U \cap W = \{0\} $ and $U + W = V$. The first fact is obvious, since if $v \in U \cap W$ then $Sv = v = -v$, so must be $0$. The second one is giving me trouble. I want to prove that for any $v \in V$, you can express it as $\mu u + \nu w$ for some $u \in U$ and $w \in W$, but how can I do that? Or is there an easier way?

Another part of the question:

> Deduce that $V$ has a basis with respect to which the matrix of $S$ is the diagonal matrix:
>   $$ \left(\begin{matrix}
> I_r & 0 \\
> 0 & -I_{n-r}
> \end{matrix}\right)$$

Here, I believe $n$ is supposed to be dimension of $V$. Am I correct to think I can deduce this by selecting a basis for $U$ with $r$ elements, extending to a basis for $V$ by unioning a basis for $W$ with $n-r$ elements (since it's a direct sum), then I'm basically done, since at this point I can just write down the matrix for $S$? OR is there something more I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, just notice that
$$v=\frac{v+Sv}{2}+\frac{v-Sv}{2},$$and
$$S\left(\frac{v+Sv}{2}\right)=\frac{Sv+S^2v}{2}=\frac{v+Sv}{2},$$
$$S\left(\frac{v-Sv}{2}\right)=\frac{Sv-S^2v}{2}=-\frac{v-Sv}{2},$$which gives you the decomposition of $v$ in $U\oplus W$.

For the second part, your reasoning is perfectly correct.